# Python Eve mongodb does not return all data

Tags: python, mongodb, eve

I setup Python Eve with Mongodb, and were able to send a GET request and get the following response:

```
<resource href="necklace" title="necklace">
<link rel="last" href="necklace?page=798" title="last page"/>
<link rel="next" href="necklace?page=2" title="next page"/>
<link rel="parent" href="/" title="home"/>
<_meta>
<max_results>25</max_results>
<page>1</page>
<total>19941</total>
</_meta>
<resource href="necklace/5a8f2b4d43999a19e8b2225e" title="Necklace">
<_created>Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT</_created>
<_etag>252d448cbc5c08a8d5c9e8ece10f2c3e6a93df1d</_etag>
<_id>5a8f2b4d43999a19e8b2225e</_id>
<_updated>Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT</_updated>
</resource>
```

The _id is correct. However, other entries of the document are not returned. Was it an error in settings.py configuration of Python Eve?

Here is the data in MongoDB:

```
_id
time
subject
aX (array)
aY (array)
aZ (array)
```

Comment: Do you have any [projections](http://python-eve.org/features.html#projections) set for the resource or globally limiting the returned fields?

Comment: Also Include the config file to find the issue..